# Do ports need to be forwarded to avoid errors online?

Tags: technical-issues, animal-crossing-new-leaf

I've had many problems with New Leaf, getting the error with the picture of Mr. Resetti very often. If this is a problem on my end, what can I do to fix it?

There's only one error in the game that I know of. It's basically the disconnection error with a picture of Mr. Resetti. I don't know what it says word for word.

Comment: can you go into a bit more detail? like what is the error saying?

Comment: Like @JLaBella is saying what kind of error?

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: It's sort of important for you to provide the exact wording if you expect us to help you diagnose it.

Comment: Also: Have you been changing the 3DS system clock?  When exactly does the error occur (and when does it not occur)?  Does it happen when you have friends online? Does it happen when you visit someone else, or have visitors?

Comment: No, I never change the clock. It occurs when I have friends in my town or I'm in theirs. It often occurs when someone new is coming to a town.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No the servers are Nintendo's.  You don't need to forward any ports since you aren't hosting a server for the game session.

I think it has to do with a weak wifi connection either yours or your friends, this happens to me every so often too :c Just make sure you do things like go to the island and go on tours since this will save your progress from those points.

Comment: The host can also press start to save (assuming not on the island)